# git workflow with rebasing

Tags: git, git-rebase

I've worked so far with SVN, GIT and Mercurial, for the latter two the workflow always consisted just of pull / merge / push. Now I'm working on a project where the workflow involves rebasing often from parent branch and I'm not sure I understand entirely what is happening or if my workflow is the right one. I'm doing all of my work in a designated branch, so:

```
git checkout dvl_bkend      // This is 'parent' branch
git checkout -b dvl_bogdan  // Created my own branch
```

Now all of below from my own branch. As I start a coding session:

```
git pull --rebase -s recursive -X ours origin dvl_bkend
```

Do coding and stuff, as soon as I have something stable-ish

```
git add stuff
git commit stuff
// rinse and repeat above two steps
```

Now when I have something ready for push.

```
git pull --rebase -s recursive -X ours origin dvl_bkend
```

At this point I would want to push to my dvl_bogdan but I can't saying that I need to pull first. So I:

```
git pull origin dvl_bogdan
```

Now this gives me conflicts that I need to merge (no ideea why this is happening?) and at this point I'm guessing something is not right. Anyway if I resolve conflicts I can then:

```
git push origin dvl_bogdan
```

Repeat all steps above until I'm ready for a pull request. Then repeat them some more. Where am I messing up with my flow? I've somehow managed to get in a situation where rebasing kept applying duplicate commits:

```
   bogdan   5b31717  Merge branch 'develop_bogdan' of xx into develop_bogdan     8 May 2013

   Bogdan Neacsa    810d753  Updated payment service to recieve an Account entity now rather that creating it itself. Also change…   8 May 2013

   bogdan   429f97b  Fix to model and service in payments. Quick fix to tests after changes.     8 May 2013

   Bogdan Neacsa    7c6ff32  Updated payment service to recieve an Account entity now rather that creating it itself. Also change…   8 May 2013

   bogdan   d74ce5a  Fix to model and service in payments. Quick fix to tests after changes.     8 May 2013

   Bogdan Neacsa    8ab401e  Updated payment service to recieve an Account entity now rather that creating it itself. Also change…   8 May 2013

   bogdan   259349b  Fix to model and service in payments. Quick fix to tests after changes.     8 May 2013
```

Thanks,
Bogdan

**EDIT: ------------ part unclear to me -------------------**

So I'm on my dvl_bogdan branch, and it's synced with me remote branch, that is if I do:

```
git pull origin dvl_bogdan
```

This states I'm up to date. Now I do:

```
git pull --rebase -s recursive -X ours origin dvl_bkend
```

And this does not give me any conflicts. But now when I try:

```
git push origin dvl_bogdan
```

It asks me to do a pull before I can push and this pull will give me conflicts. I can't really understand what is going one here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expicitly on the unclear part:

```
git pull origin dvl_bogdan
```

This will do a `git fetch`, which updates origin/dvl_bogdan and a `git merge`, which tries to apply all changes from origin/dvl_bogdan to your local dvl_bogdan. If it tells you, you are up to date. Then no one else pushed on that branch. (As expected as it seems you intend to work on this branch alone.)

```
git pull --rebase -s recursive -X ours origin dvl_bkend
```

This will do again a `git fetch` to update origin/dvl_bkend. Then a rebase will copy all your changes and apply them to origin/dvl_bkend. The resulting branch is completely unrelated to your dvl_bogdan. Use `gitk origin/dvl_bogdan...dvl_bogdan` now to see your situation:
You have a common base, on which there is one branch(1) with your original commits ending on origin/dvl_bogdan and another branch(2) with contains changes from dvl_bkend with the copies of your changes on top.

```
git push origin dvl_bogdan
```

Now you try to push the branch(2) to branch(1), which does not work as this is no fast forward push.

To solve this, face the fact that origin/dvl_bkend and origin/dvl_bogdan are two different, already published branches. You need to merge both with a merge commit, use `git fetch && git merge origin/dvl_bkend` or simply `git pull`, which is doing exactly the same.

Alternatively it is possible to do a force push to update dvl_bogdan anyway, but be really sure you know what you are doing in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The general idea sounds perfectly fine. A few comments:

- A local branches is able to track its corresponding remote upstream branch. Setting an upstream branch is always a good idea, as it is the default for many operations like push and pull. Use `git branch -vv` to see which local branches you have and which remote branch they track.
- Rebasing is changing history. ***Never change history you already published.*** This will lead to duplicate commit entries otherwise. A correctly set upstream helps you with that.
- Set `git config push.default` to a good value. (see `git help config`) I would recommend "current" or "simple" if you have a recent git version.
- Be sure you understand the meaning of "-s recursive -X ours". It might ignore upstream changes needed for the project.
- Consider setting merge.ff=false. This will make sure whenever you do a merge a corresponding merge commit is created. But remember now to always pull with the `--rebase` option, otherwise each pull will create a merge commit, too. - A good alias is convenient.

I would recommend the following slightly adapted workflow:

- first set up you config:

  ```
  git config --global push.default current
  git config --global merge.ff false
  git config --global alias.up 'pull --rebase'
  ```
- create your local branch

  ```
  git checkout dvl_bkend
  git branch -vv # dvl_bkend should track something like "origin/dvl_bkend"
  git branch -m dvl_bogdan # creating your own branch by renaming the other is an easy way of tracking the original upstream
  ```
- Work on the code. Commit frequently whenever you have finished some task. You can only roll back to states you committed. Once in a while do `git up` to integrate upstream changes and notice conflicting changes.
- Once you are finished with your work and think about making it available to others:

  ```
  git rebase -i # have a look on your commits. You can reorder them, squash them together, correct errors in commit messages, etc.

  git log -p -w --reverse  @{u}.. # a final look at all the changes you are about to push

  git push --set-upstream # push your changes to your own remote branch and change the upstream to track your own branch from now on.
  ```
- once you have pushed you final commits, you want to merge the branch back:

  ```
  git merge origin/dvl_bkend # optional, to notice potential merge conflicts
  git checkout dvl_bkend
  git merge --no-ff origin/dvl_bogdan
  git push
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the input. But why am I forced before doing a push to my own remote branch, to do a pull from there? That is the part that I don't understand really and that I think caused my branch to fail in the first place.

Comment: No, you always pull from your current upstream. - This will be the `origin/dvl_bkend` before the push, which sets it to `origin/dvl_bogdan` then.

Comment: And after push when it sets upstream to origin/dvl_bogdan will pull --rebase still get the changes from origin/dvl_bkend ? Also workflow is that I don't touch dvl_bkend just issue pull request there. But after pull request I keep my branch and go on development until new pull request and so on. Can this break setup in any way?

Comment: No, then it fetches from origin/dvl_bogdan, i.e. it will usually not update anything. It also makes no sense to do so as this would rewrite already published commits. - If you want the changes from dvl_bkend do : `git fetch && git merge origin/dvl_bkend`

Comment: If you have a long running branch on which you are working alone. Then a rebase is pretty much useless. `git pull --rebase` makes only sense for small branches until you push them.

Comment: I have the dvl_bkend from which multiple developers each have their own long running branches dvl_devname. From what I understood the rebase from dvl_bkend should make sure that each dvl_devname is properly synced with dvl_bkend.

Comment: In that case you definitely do not want a rebase. (See other answer.)